# How to squash the latest commit into a specific commit (which is not the previous commit)?

Tags: git, git-squash

Suppose I am trying to rebase my current branch which has changes on top of master :-

```
And am presented with an interactive window like this with all the new commits listed:

pick A Commit message A
pick B Commit message B
pick C Commit message C
pick D Commit message D
pick E Commit message E
```

And I want to squash E to C and not to the previous commit D. Is there a way to do that?

Coz If I do this

```
pick A Commit message A
pick B Commit message B
pick C Commit message C
pick D Commit message D
squash E Commit message E
```

it will always squash E to D but I want to squash E into some previous commit that I can choose like C or B or A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reorder the lines in the "interactive window" any way you wish and rebasing will reorder the corresponding commits. For example, you can move the line for commit C so it is above the line for commit E:

```
pick A Commit message A
pick B Commit message B
pick D Commit message D
pick C Commit message C
squash E Commit message E
```

Now the resulting history will have the changes from commits A, B, and D in that order, then a new commit with the changes from commits C and E squashed into a single commit.

Or, move the line for commit E so it is below the line for commit C:

```
pick A Commit message A
pick B Commit message B
pick C Commit message C
squash E Commit message E
pick D Commit message D
```

This will keep the changes from commits A and B in that order, then create a new commit with the combined changes of C and E, and finally a new commit with the same changes as D.

Comment: Great answer! I didn't know you can change the order, game changer.